# Postgres using unperformant plan when rerun

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I'm importing a non circular graph and flattening the ancestors to an array per code. This works fine (for a bit): ~45s for 400k codes over ~900k edges.

However, after the first successful execution Postgres decides to stop using the `Nested Loop` and the update query performance drops drastically: ~2s per code.

I can force the issue by putting a `vacuum` right before the update but I am curious why the unoptimization is happening.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_anc;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_rel;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_edges;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_codes; 

CREATE TABLE tmp_rel (
  from_id BIGINT,
  to_id   BIGINT,
);

COPY tmp_rel FROM 'rel.txt' WITH DELIMITER E'\t' CSV HEADER;

CREATE TABLE tmp_edges(
  start_node BIGINT,
  end_node   BIGINT
);

INSERT INTO tmp_edges(start_node, end_node) 
  SELECT from_id AS start_node, to_id AS end_node 
  FROM   tmp_rel;

CREATE INDEX tmp_edges_end ON tmp_edges (end_node);

CREATE TABLE tmp_codes (
  id     BIGINT,
  active SMALLINT,
);

COPY tmp_codes FROM 'codes.txt' WITH DELIMITER E'\t' CSV HEADER;

CREATE TABLE tmp_anc(
   code      BIGINT,
   ancestors BIGINT[]
);

INSERT INTO tmp_anc 
  SELECT DISTINCT(id) 
  FROM   tmp_codes 
  WHERE  active = 1;

CREATE INDEX tmp_anc_codes ON tmp_anc_codes (code);

VACUUM; -- Need this for the update to execute optimally

UPDATE tmp_anc sa SET ancestors = (
  WITH RECURSIVE ancestors(code) AS (
    SELECT start_node FROM tmp_edges WHERE end_node = sa.code
  UNION
    SELECT se.start_node
    FROM   tmp_edges se, ancestors a
    WHERE  se.end_node = a.code
  )
  SELECT array_agg(code) FROM ancestors
);
```

Table stats:

```
tmp_rel     507 MB  0 bytes
tmp_edges   74 MB   37 MB
tmp_codes   32 MB   0 bytes
tmp_anc     22 MB   8544 kB
```

Explains:

Without VACUUM before UPDATE:

```
Update on tmp_anc sa  (cost=10000000000.00..11081583053.74 rows=10 width=46) (actual time=38294.005..38294.005 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on tmp_anc sa  (cost=10000000000.00..11081583053.74 rows=10 width=46) (actual time=3300.974..38292.613 rows=10 loops=1)
        SubPlan 2
          ->  Aggregate  (cost=108158305.25..108158305.26 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=3829.253..3829.253 rows=1 loops=10)
                CTE ancestors
                  ->  Recursive Union  (cost=81.97..66015893.05 rows=1872996098 width=8) (actual time=0.037..3827.917 rows=45 loops=10)
                        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tmp_edges  (cost=81.97..4913.18 rows=4328 width=8) (actual time=0.022..0.022 rows=2 loops=10)
                              Recheck Cond: (end_node = sa.code)
                              Heap Blocks: exact=12
                              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tmp_edges_end  (cost=0.00..80.89 rows=4328 width=0) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=2 loops=10)
                                    Index Cond: (end_node = sa.code)
                        ->  Merge Join  (cost=4198.89..2855105.79 rows=187299177 width=8) (actual time=163.746..425.295 rows=10 loops=90)
                              Merge Cond: (a.code = se.end_node)
                              ->  Sort  (cost=4198.47..4306.67 rows=43280 width=8) (actual time=0.012..0.016 rows=5 loops=90)
                                    Sort Key: a.code
                                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                                    ->  WorkTable Scan on ancestors a  (cost=0.00..865.60 rows=43280 width=8) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=5 loops=90)
                              ->  Materialize  (cost=0.42..43367.08 rows=865523 width=16) (actual time=0.010..337.592 rows=537171 loops=90)
                                    ->  Index Scan using tmp_edges_end on edges se  (cost=0.42..41203.27 rows=865523 width=16) (actual time=0.009..247.547 rows=537171 loops=90)
                ->  CTE Scan on ancestors  (cost=0.00..37459921.96 rows=1872996098 width=8) (actual time=1.227..3829.159 rows=45 loops=10)
```

With VACUUM before UPDATE:

```
Update on tmp_anc sa  (cost=0.00..2949980136.43 rows=387059 width=14) (actual time=74701.329..74701.329 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on tmp_anc sa  (cost=0.00..2949980136.43 rows=387059 width=14) (actual time=0.336..70324.848 rows=387059 loops=1)
        SubPlan 2
          ->  Aggregate  (cost=7621.50..7621.51 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.180..0.180 rows=1 loops=387059)
                CTE ancestors
                  ->  Recursive Union  (cost=0.42..7583.83 rows=1674 width=8) (actual time=0.005..0.162 rows=32 loops=387059)
                        ->  Index Scan using tmp_edges_end on tmp_edges  (cost=0.42..18.93 rows=4 width=8) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=2 loops=387059)
                              Index Cond: (end_node = sa.code)
                        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..753.14 rows=167 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.019 rows=10 loops=2700448)
                              ->  WorkTable Scan on ancestors a  (cost=0.00..0.80 rows=40 width=8) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=5 loops=2700448)
                              ->  Index Scan using tmp_edges_end on tmp_edges se  (cost=0.42..18.77 rows=4 width=16) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=2 loops=12559395)
                                    Index Cond: (end_node = a.code)
                ->  CTE Scan on ancestors  (cost=0.00..33.48 rows=1674 width=8) (actual time=0.007..0.173 rows=32 loops=387059)
```

Comment: Hard to say without `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` output for the first execution, but maybe the `VACUUM` just left time enough for autoanalyze to gather statistics? If you `ANALYZE` the tables before the `UPDATE`, can you still observe the effect?

Comment: added the explain analyze but had to change the amount of codes from 400k to 10 so it runs to completion.
`Merge Join  (cost=4198.89..2855105.79 rows=187299177` :(

Comment: None of the tables seem to have a PK (or UNIQUE index), also  you should run `vacuum  analyze` on the tables after populating the tables, this will update the statistics.

Comment: The only two tables used for the update are `tmp_anc` and `tmp_edges`. I don't think `tmp_anc` needs a PK since it's `codes` column is the subject of the iteration and `tmp_anc` has an index on `end_node` which is heavily used.

Just to rule it out though, added the PKs, no changes in performance.

Really just trying to figure out how the query can execute perfectly fine the first time, but subsequent executions need a vacuum.

Answer (score 0):

The first execution plan has really bad estimates (`Bitmap Index Scan on tmp_edges_end` estimates 4328 instead of 2 rows), while the second execution has good estimates and thus chooses a good plan.
So something between the two executions you quote above must have changed the estimates.

Moreover, you say that the first execution of the `UPDATE` (for which we have no `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` output) was fast.

The only good explanation for the initial performance drop is that it takes the autovacuum daemon some time to collect statistics for the new tables. This normally improves query performance, but of course it can also work the other way around.

Also, a `VACUUM` usually doesn't fix performance issues. Could it be that you used `VACUUM (ANALYZE)`?

It would be interesting to know how things are when you collect statistics before your initial `UPDATE`:

```
ANALYZE tmp_edges;
```

When I read your query more closely, however, I wonder why you use a correlated subquery for that. Maybe it would be faster to do something like:

```
UPDATE tmp_anc sa
   SET ancestors = a.codes
   FROM (WITH RECURSIVE ancestors(code, start_node) AS
            (SELECT tmp_anc.code, tmp_edges.start_node
                FROM tmp_edges
                   JOIN tmp_anc ON tmp_edges.end_node = tmp_anc.code
             UNION
             SELECT a.code, se.start_node
                FROM tmp_edges se
                   JOIN ancestors a ON se.end_node = a.code
            )
         SELECT code,
                array_agg(start_node) AS codes
            FROM ancestors
            GROUP BY (code)
        ) a
   WHERE sa.code = a.code;
```

(This is untested, so there may be mistakes.)

Comment: The second explain analyze posted above (the correctly planned query) is the first execution. The slow one is every attempt after that.

Thanks for posting your optimizations for the query, i'll look into them later today.

Just to reiterate, the first time I run this the query takes the optimized route, it's every subsequent time after without forcing new statistics that it's performance drops significantly.

Comment: Please explain the "new statistics": you said you were running `VACUUM`, which does not collect statistics.

Comment: Another weird thing about your first execution plan is that it looks like `enable_seqscan` has been set to `off` (observe the strange high starting cost for the sequential scan). Do you change optimizer parameters between executions? All in all, many things are unclear here, and the more clearly you can describe what's going on, the better chances there are for a solution.

Comment: To be as clear as possible, the query above is executed as is, in order. There are no additionally commands I am not showing. The "new statistics" is the `Without VACUUM before UPDATE` `explain analyze` I have posted above. The other `explain analyze` is the original, first run. I understand the vacuum isn't collecting statistics, which is why I posted this question. This seems all too weird and it's my first encounter with such inconsistency. Running `vacuum (analyze)` also provides the correct plan but I feel there is clearly something I am missing about the planner here.